# Methods with generic type parameter can pass generic type parameters

Tags: java

I have instance with getters and setters in my **Customer** Class

```
private Collection<CustomersDetails> customerDetails = new ArrayList<CustomersDetails>();

    public Collection<CustomersDetails> getCustomerDetails() {
        return customerDetails;
    }
    public void setCustomerDetails(Collection<CustomersDetails> customerDetails) {
        this.customerDetails = customerDetails;
    }
```

but when i am trying to pass

```
CustomersDetails customersDetails = new CustomersDetails();

customersDetails.set....
customersDetails.set....


Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setCustomerDetails(customersDetails);
```

its giving me error

```
The method setCustomerDetails(Collection<CustomersDetails>) in the type Customer is not applicable for the arguments (CustomersDetails)
```

Why its so , when my collection is of **CustomersDetails** type??

Comment: I don't see any raw types here. This is just a regular type mismatch.

Comment: @Radiodef You're right.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Customer` class has a method

```
public void setCustomerDetails(Collection<CustomersDetails> customerDetails) {
    this.customerDetails = customerDetails;
}
```

You are trying to invoke it with an argument of type `CustomersDetails`. A `CustomersDetails` is not a `Collection<CustomersDetails>`. Wrap the element in a `List` or other `Collection`.

Something like

```
customer.setCustomerDetails(Arrays.asList(customersDetails));
```